# How to get indexPath over touched button?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I've got dynamic tableView and one problem. In each tableCell are two buttons. 
I'm trying to get indexPath.row on button touched but with no success.

My code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.homeTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];      

    NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);


}
```

How can I get indexPath.row for touced button (Segue connections are over this two buttons->two connections)?

Comment: I'm geting nil for that-> NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);

Comment: The `%d` specifier shouldn't display `nil`. Maybe you have selected the first row of which the index is 0.

Comment: When I select second or third row always is nil.

Comment: I wouldn't have expected this to work. When you have a `IBOutlet` for a control in a tableview, the `UITableViewCell` is not selected when you press the button. You need some linkage from the button back to the `UITableViewCell`. If you've just made the button a subview of the cell, itself, you can retrieve the cell via `superview`, and then retrieve the indexPath via `UITableView` method `indexPathForCell`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not working because you do not select row when you click button.

With two buttons I would disconnect your segues from buttons and do 2 manual segues in IB then add code like that to handle them:

```
-(void)button1Pressed:(id)sender {
    UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *clickedButtonIndexPath = [self.homeTableView indexPathForCell:clickedCell];
    ...
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourManualSegueIdentifier1" sender:self];
}
```

**Edit for second option:**

In your MyTableViewCell.h:

```
@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
    ...    
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath;
    ...
@end
```

In your MyTableViewCell.m:

```
-(void)button1Pressed:(id)sender {
    ...
    NSInteger row = cellIndexPath.row;
    ...
}
```

In your MyTableViewController.m:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MyTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];      
    }
    // remember index here!
    [cell setCellIndexPath:indexPath];
    ....
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: But I got IBaction for buttons in uitableviewcell.h

Comment: So If you have custom `UITableViewCell` class you could extend it with indexPath property and update it when cell is being retrieved in `cellForTableView:` but only if you do not plan to insert rows in the middle or delete them.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand you. Can you please explain me with more details please? P.S. I do not plan to insert or delete rows in the middle.

Comment: If you subclass `UITableViewCell` you can add additional property there which will be named for instance `cellIndexPath`. In your viewController where you return cells inside 'cellForRowAtIndexPath:' you can just set `cellIndexPath` to `indexPath` argument, then inside your button1Pressed you can get it from self.cellIndexPath.

Comment: Could you pls do examples in separate answer because I do not know how to do that?

Comment: I understand you but not your whole solution. What I get with "-(void)button1Pressed:(id)sender {
"?

Comment: You wanted to get index of a cell to which button was assigned. This method is supposed to be your IBAction for your custom `UITableViewCell`'s button. So if you press button you will get to that function. From there you could call `[[[self superview] superview] performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSequeBtn1" sender:self]]`. In `prepareForSegue` you could read the cell from sender argument thus get the row index as well. Anyway your solution with button seems to be less complicated. You can always subclass your button and keep indexPath in there instead of using tag so you will get section as well

Comment: Thank's for your detail explanation. I've learned some new things.

Comment: in iOS8..this will always give 0. Please see this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784630/how-to-find-indexpath-for-tapped-button-in-tableview-using-seque/27292570#27292570

Answer (score 10):

Apple change the UITableViewCell hierarchy in iOS 7

Using iOS 6.1 SDK

```
<UITableViewCell>
   | <UITableViewCellContentView>
   |    | <UILabel>
```

Using iOS 7 SDK

```
<UITableViewCell>
   | <UITableViewCellScrollView>
   |    | <UITableViewCellContentView>
   |    |    | <UILabel>
```

So if you want to get indexpath at button index then use following code
Using iOS 6 or later SDK

```
UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *clickedButtonPath = [book_table indexPathForCell:clickedCell];
    NSLog(@"index=%@",clickedButtonPath);
```

Using iOS 7 or 7+ SDK

```
 UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[[sender superview] superview]superview];
    NSIndexPath *clickedButtonPath = [book_table indexPathForCell:clickedCell];
    NSLog(@"index=%ld",(long)clickedButtonPath.item);
```

Answer (score 6):

I am not using storyboard but once i did it in simple viewconroller based project, i think this may help you.

```
 - (IBAction)goToNew:(id)sender 
{
   UIButton *btn = (UIButton*) sender;
   UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) [btn superview];
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell]; 
   int row = indexPath.row;
}
```

Comment: +1 Agreed. You need to map back from button to `UITableViewCell` and then to the `indexPath`. The specifics may vary depending upon the relationship between the button and the cell (e.g. if button is in a content view, you'll have an extra level to go through, but hopefully CroiOS gets the idea).

Comment: yes @Rob if it is in content view then UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) btn.superview.superview; should be there.

Comment: But I got IBaction for buttons in uitableviewcell.h

Comment: then give the target of cell to your viewcontroller in which your tableview exist.   like write cell.target = self in your controller and write a - (IBAction)goToNew:(id)sender  method in your controller .

Comment: in iOS8..this will always give 0. Please see this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784630/how-to-find-indexpath-for-tapped-button-in-tableview-using-seque/27292570#27292570

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the touch happened to the UIButton instead of the UITableView / UITableViewCell.

Check with :

```
NSLog(@"%@",[sender class]);
```

Comment: yes, sorry but I did not how to explain that. Touch is happened over UIButton. Can I get indexPath.row?

Comment: if the button is a subview of UITableViewCell, then you can use [button superview] method to access the cell, then accessing it's indexPath.row property.

Comment: But I got IBaction for buttons in uitableviewcell.h

Answer (score 0):

Solved over button.tag

In "cellForRowAtIndexPath" I set button.tag = indexPath.row and then in "- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{"

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton*) sender;
NSLog(@"%d", btn.tag);
```

Comment: Good solution but only if you have one section in your table.

Comment: And you do not remove cells without reloading the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

give button `tag = indexpath.row+100;`

and get..

```
-(IBAction)ShowListView:(id)sender
{

    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;

    int Iindex = btn.tag-100;

    NSLog(@"button title is %@",btn.titleLabel.text);
    NSLog(@"button id is %d",Iindex);

    NSLog(@"array category is....%@",arrayCategory);
```