# How to find indexPath for tapped button in tableView Using Seque

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` using prototype cell.

The cells have a `UIButton` that show a `UIViewController` (Modal) using `Segue`.

My question is : How can i pass `IndexPath` of cell to second view controller

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showGamerDetail"]) {

            //its not worked:
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self._tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            nDetailViewController *destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
            destinationViewController.selectedRowTitle = [gamers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        destinationViewController.indexPath = indexPath;
        destinationViewController.delegate = self;
    }
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Forget for a moment that you are using storyboard, and let's try to follow the best approach.

You have several solution, but for my opinion, just 1 of these is optimal: `delegation pattern`.

First, you should **extend your cell**, and **using delegation** to return the cell when the user press the button. Then, you should use `indexPathForCell` to get the `indexPath`.

Let's see the approaches:

### Cell by button position

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
  CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero
                                   toView:self.tableView];
  NSIndexPath *tappedIP = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

  // When necessary 
  // UITableViewCell *clickedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:tappedIP];
}
```

the solution above is certainly the **most rapid to implement**, but **it is not the best from the  point of view of the design/architecture**. Moreover you get the `indexPath` but you need then to calculate every other info. This is a cool method, but would say not the best.

### Cell by while cycle on the button superviews

```
// ContactListViewController.m

- (IBAction)emailContact:(id)sender {
    YMContact *contact = [self contactFromContactButton:sender];
    // present composer with `contact`...
}

- (YMContact *)contactFromContactButton:(UIView *)contactButton {
    UIView *aSuperview = [contactButton superview];
    while (![aSuperview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        aSuperview = [aSuperview superview];
    }
    YMContactCell *cell = (id) aSuperview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    return [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Get the cell in this way is less performant of the former, and it is not elegant as well.

### Cell by button tag

```
- (CustomCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.theLabel.text = self.theData[indexPath.row];
    cell.button.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return cell;
}

-(void)doSomething:(UIButton *) sender {
    NSLog(@"%@",self.theData[sender.tag]);
    //sender.tag will be equal to indexPath.row
}
```

Absolutely no. Use the tag could seem a cool solution, but the **tag of a control can be used for other reasons**, like the next responder etc. I don't like this approach.

### Cell by design pattern

```
// YMContactCell.h
@protocol YMContactCellDelegate
- (void)contactCellEmailWasTapped:(YMContactCell*)cell;
@end

@interface YMContactCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<YMContactCellDelegate> delegate;
@end

// YMContactCell.m
- (IBAction)emailContact:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate contactCellEmailWasTapped:self];
}

// ContactListViewController.m
- (void)contactCellEmailWasTapped:(YMContactCell*)cell;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    YMContact *contact = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // present composer with `contact` ...
}
```

**This is my favourite solution**. 
Using `delegation` or `blocks` is a really nice approach and **you can pass all the parameters you want**. In fact you could want to send back directly the needed info, without having to calculate them later.

Enjoy ;)

Comment: Really helpful answer

Comment: `Cell by button tag` is best method and Easy to implement . You Rock bro.

Comment: Thanks man, but I have to say that it is not. You should not rely on tag honestly as it can be used for other purposes. From a correct design point of view, the last approach is the best for me.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple solution, if you want to point to the same segue of the selected cell.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

    [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First make a global int variable `selecteIndex`;

In your cell, give your button tag similar to cell's `indexPath.row` value

E.g. `btn.tag = indexPath.row;`

The assing & call action on click of that button

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
    selectedIndex = btn.tag;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueName" sender:self];
}
```

Then at end of your view write this function

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueName"]) {
        viewController *dvc = (viewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        [dvc setSelected:selectedIndex];
    };
}
```

Comment: This just gives the row of the index path, not the index path itself.

Comment: I sometimes use the button.titleLabel.tag to store the row or section number. You could store the row in the button.tag, and the section in the button.titleLabel tag, or some variation like that.