# Issue assigning action to UIButton in TableView Cell creation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I am populating a `TableView` dynamically with data called from a server.  I have 2 main files, one for the new cell and one for handling the population of the cells within the `TableView`  Now when I assign `[cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(addFriend:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` to my button within the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and I put an output to log the action of the clicking of the button, nothing happens.

Here is what I am doing:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  .......
  /* Setup button action */
        [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(addFriend:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
- (IBAction)addFriend:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Add friend.");
}
```

Cell Creation:

```
HomePageTimelineCell *cell = (HomePageTimelineCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [[HomePageTimelineCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Suggestions?

UPDATE:

Here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%d",i);
    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];// Get rid of speration border color

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"homecell";
    HomePageTimelineCell *cell = (HomePageTimelineCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [[HomePageTimelineCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    [cell initTimelineCell];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];// Set the background color to the cell

    //<!-- Set background color
    if (indexPath.row % 2) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"77d1af"];
        //<!-- Set background and text color for even cells
        [cell.button setTitleColor:[self colorWithHexString:@"7ddcb8"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cell.button.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"666666"];
    } else {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"7ddcb8"];
        //<!-- Set background and text color for even cells
        [cell.button setTitleColor:[self colorWithHexString:@"7ddcb8"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cell.button.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"ffffff"];
    }
    //<!-- if the indexRow row = 0, this is the clients username and address
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        NSArray *get = [[SSKeychain allAccounts] init];
        NSString *username = [get[0] objectForKey:@"acct"];
        //<!-- Get keyname of the address and than point to that keyname and get data
        NSString *KeyName = [[self.dataGrabed_dictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex: indexPath.row + 4];
        //<!-- create uppercase strings
        NSString *upperCaseAddress = [[self.dataGrabed_dictionary objectForKey:KeyName] uppercaseString];
        NSString *upperCaseUsername = [username uppercaseString];
        //<!-- Set associated strings
        cell.addressLabel.text = upperCaseAddress;
        cell.usernameLabel.text = upperCaseUsername;
    }
    //<!-- if the indexRow row = 1, this is the 2 cell and will show the most upcoming lawn schedule
    else if(indexPath.row == 1)
    {        //<!-- create uppercase strings
        NSString *upperCaseDay = [[self.dataGrabed_dictionary objectForKey:@"upcoming_day"] uppercaseString];
        //<!-- create uppercase strings
        NSString *upperCaseDate = [[self.dataGrabed_dictionary objectForKey:@"upcoming_date"] uppercaseString];

        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"666666"];
        cell.button.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"7ddcb8"];
        cell.button.tag = indexPath.row;

        [cell.button setTitle:@"change" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.button setTitleColor:[self colorWithHexString:@"666666"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        /* Setup button action */
        [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.dayLabel.text = upperCaseDay;//<!-- Set the day
        cell.dateLabel.text = upperCaseDate;//<!-- Set the Date
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.button];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.nextLabel];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.dayLabel];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.dateLabel];
    }
    else //<!-- Normal cell population
    {
        //<!-- Re edit labels positioning
        cell.dayLabel.frame = CGRectMake(9, 10, 200, 45);
        cell.dateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(9, 35, 300, 45);
        //<!-- Setup data called from server
        NSDictionary *innerClientData =[self.dataGrabed_dictionary objectForKey:@"scheduled_times"][i];
        NSString *innerClientDay =[self.dataGrabed_dictionary objectForKey:@"scheduled_times_day"][i];
        NSString *innerClientDate =[self.dataGrabed_dictionary objectForKey:@"scheduled_times_date"][i];
        //<!-- create uppercase strings
        NSString *upperCaseDay = [innerClientDay uppercaseString];
        //<!-- create uppercase strings
        NSString *upperCaseDate = [ innerClientDate uppercaseString];

        //<!-- Check to see if client paid
        if([[innerClientData objectForKey:@"client_paid"]  isEqual: @"0"])
        {
            NSString *amount = [innerClientData objectForKey:@"client_price"];
            NSString *pay = @"pay $";
            NSString * combined = [pay stringByAppendingString:amount];

            [cell.button setTitle:combined forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else if([[innerClientData objectForKey:@"client_paid"] isEqual: @"1"])
        {
            [cell.button setTitle:@"PAID" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        //[cell.button setTitleColor:[self colorWithHexString:@"666666"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cell.button.tag = indexPath.row;
        /* Setup button action */
        [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.dayLabel.text = upperCaseDay;//<!-- Set the day
        cell.dateLabel.text = upperCaseDate;//<!-- Set the Date
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.button];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.dayLabel];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.dateLabel];

        i++;

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Here is my `HomePageTimelineCell` cell creator:

```
#import "HomePageTimelineCell.h"
#import "HomePage.h"

@implementation HomePageTimelineCell
@synthesize cellContentView;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        cellContentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 300, 85)];
        cellContentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


        _usernameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(9, 10, 300, 45)];
        _usernameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleSDGothicNeo-SemiBold" size:30.0];
        _usernameLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        _addressLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(9, 40, 300, 45)];
        _addressLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleSDGothicNeo-Light" size:20.0];
        _addressLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _addressLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
        _addressLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;

        _nextLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(9, 0, 100, 45)];
        _nextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin" size:25.0];
        _nextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _nextLabel.text = @"NEXT";

        _dayLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(9, 25, 200, 45)];
        _dayLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleSDGothicNeo-SemiBold" size:35.0];
        _dayLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        _dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(9, 50, 300, 45)];
        _dateLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin" size:25.0];
        _dateLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


        // IMPACT BUTTON STYLES 
        _button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        _button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0f;
        _button.frame = CGRectMake(220, 20, 80, 45);



        /* ADD ALL THE CONTENT */
        [self addSubview:cellContentView];
        [cellContentView addSubview:_usernameLabel];
        [cellContentView addSubview:_addressLabel];



    }
    return self;
}

- (void) initTimelineCell
{
    cellContentView.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
    cellContentView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

    configured = YES;
}

- (bool) configured
{
    return configured;
}

@end
```

Comment: Where do you create the UIButton?  Are you creating a subclass of UITableViewCell?  Could you paste that code?  Also, I would try adding the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method to see if the row is actually getting selected rather than the button when you tap on it.

Comment: @JoshGafni I do have the `didselectro...` and it does work.

Comment: Is cell.button an IBOutlet?

Comment: @christruman no I don't believe so.  The only place I give the definition to go to the button target is when I use `[cell.button addtarget...]`

Comment: Okay, then the button probably doesn't exist when you try and add the target.  If the button is nil, then adding a target won't do anything.  You can put a breakpoint right before the addTarget line, and po cell.button to see if its nil.

Comment: I am defining the button in my subclass header using: `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *
    button;`

Comment: @ChrisTruman here is what it prints out: `<UIButton: 0x7facb9df0ed0; frame = (220 20; 80 45); opaque = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x7facb9df10b0>>`

Answer (score 2):

Premise that you should provide more code to have a clear idea of what is happening,
this is not the best approach.

At least I hope you are adding the target just if the cell is `nil` and you are init that and not more and more time :)

But anyway, the **correct approach in functionality and design**, is to implement the **button action in the cell subclass**, and **return back by a delegate** the cell where the button touched was.

I explained the various approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784630/how-to-find-indexpath-for-tapped-button-in-tableview-using-seque/23785231#23785231), the last one is this.

Enjoy **clean code** and **good design** ;)

Comment: {{Citation needed}} on the so called "correct approach"

Comment: changed in `best approach` :) ok?

Comment: @Matteogobbi I still don't know why It is not running correctly.  Check update

Comment: In my post i said another thing: you have to configure the button in your subclass. So the target of the button is in the subclass, and from there, by the delegation pattern, you return the cell (where the button touched was on) to the delegate (that will be your viewController)