# MapView over UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, tableview, cell, user-interaction

I'm trying to have a mapView cover an entire UITableViewCell and disable all user activity on this mapView, but still have the cell clickable. However, this mapView (even though I sent subview to back) is intercepting the user clicks and is causing the didSelectRow method to never get called.

Comment: Determine the CGPoint of the click instead of using didSelectRowAtIndexPath ... something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784630/how-to-find-indexpath-for-tapped-button-in-tableview-using-seque

Comment: How are you disabling user interaction?

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the way below:

You add a view above mapView and set background color is `clearColor`. I think it will resolve your problem.

Comment: But it disables the annotations, scrolling of map etc also. Any other way to handle the tap on cell?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can disable map clicking completely.

Do this: add a UiButton over the map with a clear background, this button can catch all pressing.