# Button's Tag are same in TableView

Tags: objective-c

I add view for header, here is my code:

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
    view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:127.0/255.0 green:229.0/255.0 blue:232.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 0, 150, 50)];
    label.text = sectionArray[section];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];

    button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.myTableView.frame.size.width - 50, 15, 20, 20)];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.tag = section;
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(extentFunction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [view addSubview:label];
    [view addSubview:button];
    return view;
}

-(void)extentFunction {

    switch (button.tag) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"0");
            break;
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"1");
            break;
        case 2:
            NSLog(@"2");
            break;
        case 3:
            NSLog(@"3");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

The question is: the button's tag is same of each header, not the section integer (ex: first header button's tag is 0; second header button's tag is 1)that I want.

What should I do?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion :)

Comment: Firstly. Why are you adding tap Gesture on button? you should add Target to your button with selector. Something like this [button addTarget:self action:@selector(yourSelectorName:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    And secondly avoid adding Tags for your controls in tableview delegates. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784630/how-to-find-indexpath-for-tapped-button-in-tableview-using-seque

Comment: I still have no idea when I look this answer... :(

Comment: OH!!!! I already fix the code, It work!!!! Thank you very much!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As first look its clear issue of `local` & `global` variable.

You need to define your `button` as local variable and use `button` action sender as button object and get tag from  that button.

**Look at below code I think it will help you to understand your issue:**

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
    view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:127.0/255.0 green:229.0/255.0 blue:232.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 0, 150, 50)];
    label.text = sectionArray[section];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
    //Make Your Button local object not global
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.myTableView.frame.size.width - 50, 15, 20, 20)];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.tag = section;
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(extentFunction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [view addSubview:label];
    [view addSubview:button];
    return view;
}

-(IBAction)btnClick:(UIButton*)sender{
    switch (sender.tag) {
        case 0:
        NSLog(@"0");
        break;
        case 1:
        NSLog(@"1");
        break;
        case 2:
        NSLog(@"2");
        break;
        case 3:
        NSLog(@"3");
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Let me know if its working fine.

Comment: Thank you for your help!! But there also have a problem that when click button, the IBAction is not work. Is the target selector problem?

Comment: ys you ned to replace your action with new action.

Answer (score 0):

This is your custom button code which is correct.

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.myTableView.frame.size.width - 50, 15, 20, 20)];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.tag = section;
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(extentFunction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

But you also need to add its sender and event to get the touch location of your button like below code.

```
 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(extentFunction:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Now when you will click on button, extentFunction selector will get called. Now all you have to do is implement your button selector like below code.

```
-(void)extentFunction:(id)sender event:(id)event{
  NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

  CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:_yourTableViewName];
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_yourTableViewName indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
  NSLog(@"%ld",indexPath.section);
}
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thank you very much!!
I have already solve problem!
use [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
and -(IBAction)buttonClick:(UIButton *)sender